# What does in php if( $var ) match?

Tags: php, if-statement

In php, what does it match? When does it return true?

```
if( $something ) {
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php should be of interest.

Comment: Please check: PHP Manual / Language Reference / Control Structures / [if](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)

Comment: [Truthy, Falsey, type-juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php). Yes, these are highly technicaly terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if( $something ) {
}
```

Anything except `0`, `null`, `[]`, `''`, `false`, `undefined`, `"0"` will return true.

Comment: What about negative values?

Comment: With [] you mean an empty array?

Comment: Oh yes, those will return false too. Will update my answer. And yes [] is an empty array.

Comment: Negative `-1` gives **TRUE** not false. See http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php. Instead of 0 all numeric values are **TRUE**.

Comment: Good catch. I just tested it. Never thought that would be the case. Will update (again). Thanks